# PHP uploaded file is not saved and no error is shown

Tags: php, file-upload

I don't know if my code it's correct, but everything indicates success when sending..

My Form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File: <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

My Upload File

```
<?php 

if($_FILES['file']['name'])
{
    if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])
    {
        $valid_file = true;

        if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
            $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        }

        if($valid_file)
        {
            /
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/files')){
                echo "Sent";
            }else{
                echo "~Error~";
            }

        }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {       
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
    }
}

?>
```

The message that I get is "Sent", but when I go to check, the folder files is empty :s

My folder structure is:

```
/files - Here is directory where the files will come
index.php - My form
upload.php - My Logic
```

Comment: check write permission on files directory, this could be the problem but should be generate an error.

Comment: Extension is missing.. and also change folder permission

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` to see the errors

Comment: Ok, I'll check permission and extension..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the issues that I see in your code is that you do not specify a name for your "moved" file:

This line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/files')
```

Should be changed to:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/files/'.'sampleName'.$extension);// extension is the extension of the file.
```

I still assume your '/files' path is **correct** and does not have **permission** problem.

Comment: hmm.. this way "move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/files'.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].$ext)" is correct?

Comment: $ext is extension that I'm getting

Comment: Yes it is correct. But you should not use tmp_name as the final name for the file (it is not a good idea). You can use `uniqid()` to generate a unique string for your file, or get to use some special naming convention. Notify us of the result.

Comment: I tested using string "name" result: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/files/'.'name.'.$ext), after "name" I added a dot, Its not working  Warning: move_uploaded_file(/files/name.txt): failed to open stream and  Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2D0F.tmp' to '/files/name.txt'

Comment: If the problem was permission, where I check it?

Comment: Which operating system are you running these tests on? Anyway, you should be permitted to access both files. Check also the empty space of destination.

Comment: Windows 7, space of destination? My Folders is empty, is it that you wanto to know?

Comment: Go and download a registry file called TakeOwnership.reg. Search it one the net. The after installing the .reg file,  right-click on destination and source folder and from the context menu choose "Take Ownership"

Comment: I fix it, the biggest problem was the path, I had write a different path

Answer (score 1):

Same issue arises if your target folder has no write permission.

Use this command to change that:

```
chmod 775 [folder-name]
```